# Unit-testing a rest-API written in xml

Tags: java, xml, rest, unit-testing

I am new to web development and java. I have developed this rest-api using xml and it runs fine (NetBeans). However, I need to perform unit testing on it. Can someone please guide me?

Thanks in advance

```
@Path("/users")
public class users{
    String host=HelperClass.host;
    String uName=HelperClass.uName;
    String pass=HelperClass.pass;
    Connection con;

/**
 * Gets all the users in the database with the password.
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
@GET
@Path("/getusers")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public UserList getAllUsers() throws SQLException {
    UserList users;
    try
    {            
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, pass);
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        String Sql="SELECT * FROM USERS";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(Sql);
        users=new UserList();
        users.setUsers(new ArrayList<Users>());

        while(rs.next())
        {
            Users newuser=new Users();
            newuser.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            newuser.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
            users.getUsers().add(newuser);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        users=new UserList();

    }
    finally
    {
        con.close();
    }
    return users;
}

/**
 * Gets the specific user in the database.
 * @param userId
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
@GET
@Path("/getuser/{userId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Users getUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId) throws SQLException
{
    Users user;
    try
    {
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, pass);
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        String Sql="SELECT * FROM USERS where USERNAME='"+userId+"'";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(Sql);
        user=new Users();

         while(rs.next())
        {
            user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));                
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        user=new Users();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.close();
    }
    return user;
}

@POST
@Path("/setuser")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public String setUser(Users user) throws SQLException
{
    try
    {
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, pass);
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        String Sql="INSERT INTO USERS VALUES('"+user.getUsername()+"','"+user.getPassword()+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(Sql);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return "error";
    }
    finally
    {
        con.close();
    }
    return "done";
}

@DELETE
@Path("/deleteuser/{userId}")
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public String deleteUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId) throws SQLException
{
    try
    {
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, pass);
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();            


        String Sql="Delete from replies where REPLY_ID='"+userId+"'";
        stmt.executeUpdate(Sql);

         Sql="Delete from comments where USER_ID='"+userId+"'";
        stmt.executeUpdate(Sql);

        Sql="Delete from USERINFO where USERINFO_ID='"+userId+"'";
        stmt.executeUpdate(Sql);



        Sql="Delete from USERS where USERNAME='"+userId+"'";
        stmt.executeUpdate(Sql);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return "error";
    }
    finally
    {
        con.close();
    }
    return "done";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to test your rest APIs:

1> Directly invoke the methods in your Junits and verify the result

2> Use http GET/POST methods to call your APIs and verify the response.

For calling an API using a http get method, you may refer below example:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=httpClient";

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

// add request header
request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

System.out.println("Response Code : " 
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
```

For other examples, please take a look at http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give me an example of invoking it in Junit?                            And also, is the second method a Unit testing approach? Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing in your answer about writing a unit test that runs the JAX-RS application in a container and executes HTTP requests against it.